# Bugs using Qt 6.1.3 in Visual studio2019

Tags: qt, c++17, visual-studio-2019

Simply create a new MainWindow project in VisualStudio2019, there are two errors showing in error output window:

> C++ defaulted default constructor cannot be constexpr because the corresponding implicitly declared default constructor would not be constexpr

> C++ expression must have a constant value

Some setting are shown below:

QT version: 6.1.3_msvc2019_64

Windows SDK version：10.0.20348.0

Plantform tool set：Visual Studio 2019 (v142)

C++ version：ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)

Well the project is good to build and run, while showing above errors.
Someone has any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: I think it would help if you showed the code lines that produced these errors. Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe this is related: [https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85644](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85644) if the error is just an intellisense error you probably have to ignore it.